# The best solution architecture in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, collections, architecture

I am using MongoDB and I want to get data for show many times a menu with Type and Subtypes, and if I visit one subtype, the system shows the products of the subtype.

The example 1 is better to me because I just have one collection by each type, but If I do not visit any Subtype I will load all products too. Ok I know, I can use projections, but Is it possible to use projections with query? Could I project the products of just one subtype? So maybe the example 2 is the correct way in this case, but I have two collections and more relations.

What do you think is the best solution?

**Example 1**

Collection Types:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("53fae88aafb3dc3494e03225"),
"name" : "TypeProduct",
"subtypes" : [ 
{
    "name" : "Subtype1",
    "products" : [ 
    {
                "$ref" : "products",
                "$id" : ObjectId("53fee4fcafb358a62d7684c3"),
            "sku" : "0001",
        "picture" : "http...jpg"
            }, 
            {
                "$ref" : "products",
                "$id" : ObjectId("53fee656afb358a62d7684c4"),
            "sku" : "0002",
        "picture" : "http...jpg"
            } 
    ]
}, 
{
    "name" : "Subtype2",
    "products" : [ 
    {
                "$ref" : "products",
                "$id" : ObjectId("53fee4fcafb358a62d7684c3"),
            "sku" : "0001",
        "picture" : "http...jpg"
            }, 
            {
                "$ref" : "products",
                "$id" : ObjectId("53fee656afb358a62d7684c4"),
            "sku" : "0003",
        "picture" : "http...jpg"
            } 
    ]
}
]
}
```

**Example 2**

Collection Types

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("53fae88aafb3dc3494e03225"),
"name" : "TypeProduct",
"subtypes" : [ 
{
        "$ref" : "subtypes",
        "$id" : ObjectId("53fee4fcafb358a62d7684c3"),
    "name" : "Subtype1"
}, 
{
        "$ref" : "subtypes",
        "$id" : ObjectId("53fee4fcafb358a62d7684c3"),
    "name" : "Subtype2"
}
]
}
```

Collection Subtypes

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("53fee4fcafb358a62d7684c3"),
"name" : "Subtype1",
"products" : [ 
{
        "$ref" : "products",
        "$id" : ObjectId("53fee4fcafb358a62d7684c3"),
        "sku" : "0001",
    "picture" : "http...jpg"
    }, 
    {
        "$ref" : "products",
        "$id" : ObjectId("53fee656afb358a62d7684c4"),
        "sku" : "0002",
    "picture" : "http...jpg"
    } 
]
}
```

Comment: Fields prefixed with `$` are not allowed as it's a reserved character in MongoDB for other purposes.

Comment: Yes, It's generated code by Morphia, not mine.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution in MongoDB is the first one you show since it is a non relational database. About your questions, you don't have to worry, you can do everything you ask. You just need to know how to do it. About your questions:

*"Ok I know, I can use projections, but **Is it possible to use projections with query? Could I project the products of just one subtype?**"*

Yes, but not in the normal way. One solution you could try is to filter a subtype and then project only the products, like these:

*db.products.find(
{"name": "TypeName", "subtypes.name": "SubtypeName"},{"subtypes.products": 1})*

The problem here is that this will give you a list with all the subtypes of type "TypeName" and their list of products. So **this is wrong**.

You need to use [$elemMatch in the project](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) to retrieve the list of products you want:

*db.products.find({"name": "TypeName", "subtypes.name": "SubtypeName"}, {"subtypes": {$elemMatch: {"name": "SubtypeName"}}, "subtypes.products": 1 })*

Note that $elemMatch is used to limit an array field from the query results and **only returns the first element matching**.

In the use case you exposed I think this should be the solution.